# Copy a Template each time and replace using Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following data set in my `sheet 1`

[image]

And this template in `sheet 3`

[image]

I wish to

1. Copy the template from `sheet 3` to `sheet2`
2. Read the city and name from row 1 in `sheet1`
3. Replace the `City` and `Name` in sheet 2
4. Repeat it for every row in `sheet 1`

So my ideal output will be:

[image]

As you can see because we have three rows in sheet 1 the template is copied three times.

I tried this code, but it doesn't go to loop for 'sheet1'

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim ii As Long

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

For ii = 1 To 10
 copySheet.Range("A1:E3").Copy
 pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Dim j, k, L, b As String
   Dim i As Long
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim sht1 As Worksheet
   Dim sht2 As Worksheet

  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

   j = "Name"
   b = "City"

   For i = 1 To 3

    k = sht1.Range("A" & i)
    L = sht1.Range("B" & i)

    sht2.Cells.Replace what:=j, replacement:=k, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False
    sht2.Cells.Replace what:=b, replacement:=L, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False

   Next i

Next ii

 End Sub
```

Any guidance is really appreciated.

Comment: Would you be interested in a non-VBA worksheet formula solution?

Comment: Yes, it is even more appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Adam for pointing this out. My bad. The image is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't what you asked for, but you can accomplish this entirely with cell formulas.  It is a little complicated, and VBA is probably a better approach, but in case you're curious:

I am assuming your Name/City pairs are in `Sheet1!$A$1:$B$9` ****

[image]

On sheet 2, in column A, I will build a list that indicates which row to grab data from. (1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4, etc)

On sheet 2, column B, I will build a list that shows which type of result this destination row should have (Name - City Name is `1`, Name City - City is `2`, and Name - City is `3`) There are various ways of doing this.  I filled Column A with `=INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1` and column B with `=MOD(ROW()-1,3)+1`

Now my first two columns on Sheet 2 look like

[image]

Now I can use those to build indexed lookups against the original data.  Column C will have 2 different types of behavior.  It always starts with the Name, but if Column B is 2, it is followed by the City.

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$9,S A1,1)&IF(B1=2," " & INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$9, A1,2),"")`

Column D will also have two types of entries.  Always start with the City, but if Column B is `1`, follow with the name.

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$9,A1,2)&IF(B1=1," " & INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$9,A1,1),"")`

Voila

[image]

If you wanted to, you could replace all of the references to Columns A & B with the actual formulas that are in them.

Then Column C would have:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$9,INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1,1)&" "&IF(MOD(ROW()-1,3)+1=2,INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$9,INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1,2),"")
```

Make the corresponding substitutions in Column D and you can leave out Columns A&B.

[image]

One small inconvenience with this approach is that because it relies on `row()`, it can't be moved to any other row without adjusting the two index formulas ( `INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1` &`MOD(ROW()-1,3)+1`)

---

**** In the real world, I would also give your source data table a name, like `NameCityTable`  Then your first result column could look like:

```
=INDEX(NameCityTable,INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1,1)&" "&IF(MOD(ROW()-1,3)+1=2,INDEX(NameCityTable,INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1,2),"")
```

Comment: Thank you Adam it was very wise solution. However, is difficult if I want to reproduce for a larger dataset with a slight difference in the patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng1() As Variant, rng2 As Range, rng3() As Variant,k&
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    rng1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value
End With
With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    rng3 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value
End With
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    For k = LBound(rng1, 1) To UBound(rng1, 1)
        Set rng2 = .Range("A1").Offset(UBound(rng3, 1) * (k - 1)).Resize(UBound(rng3, 1), UBound(rng3, 2))
        With rng2
            .Value = rng3
            .Replace "City", rng1(k, 2)
            .Replace "Name", rng1(k, 1)
        End With
    Next k
End With
End Sub
```

Inputs:

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet3:

[image]

Output:

Sheet2:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, seems a wise idea. However, it doesn't work for cell with two name. For instance, it doesn't replace cell with this value "city name"

Comment: @MFR see inputs and outputs.  Sheet2 is what happens when I ran the code above.

Comment: thank you, I tried a few times and it didn't give me the correct results for some cells. Not sure what I'm missing. I'll come back shortly and will try again to find out the issue. I have `A` correctly but the second row is `City Name`